# How to update image after uploading in MERN, using multer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer, mern

I am working on FYP so must get  help of google and youtube. With this [link code](https://dev.to/yosraskhiri/how-to-upload-an-image-using-mern-stack-1j95), I can upload image but after refresh its not there.. how to update image after uploading it ? I want to keep it as profile pic unless a user again upload pic and that pic will be updated as profile pic. Please help and edit this code so I can insert it in FYP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you mechanism to save the image, but I think:

1. if you save an image in the filesystem and the filename is saved to the database, you can just remove the image from the filesystem and save the new image with the same name in the database.
2. if you save the image as a blob in the database, you can update as usual with SQL query